# ToggleButton -> Change TextView

Tags: java, android

Can you help me? Why does this not work? And how can I make it work! Thank you :)
The app just always shows "Im turned off!".

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ToggleButton b = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.Button);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Field);

    if (b.isChecked() == false){
        t.setText("I'm turned off!");
    }
    if (b.isChecked()==true)

            t.setText("I'm turned on!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking the status of the ToggleButton at the time of creation, which means it will only ever have the default checked value you've set for that element in your XML. You need to create a listener to detect changes and update the TextView from within the listener.

Code sample:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
       if(b.isChecked())
            t.setText("I'm turned on");
       else
            t.setText("I'm turned off"); 
   }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me :) Although I had to make b and t final!

Answer (score 0):

Because you change the text only in the onCreate method. Instead you would have to react on a change of the ToggleButton using the setOnClickListener method.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code on a setonclickListener of a Button or something.....

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (b.isChecked() == false){
        t.setText("I'm turned off!");
    }
    if (b.isChecked()==true)

            t.setText("I'm turend on!");
    }


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
yourToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                Log.e("", "on");
            } else {
                Log.e("", "Off");
            }
        }
    });
```